# difference between like and =

Tags: sql, sql-server

what is the differences between = to like ?

thanks for help :)
by the way if it's help , the error i get is: the data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator [msg 402]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi54Y.png): [image]

Comment: It depends on the context you are referring to. If you make use of `Like` the SQL engine would search for the occurrence of that string irrespective of the position in a row or of it is preceded or followed by other words in the row. Whereas , if you make use of `Where column ='string'` the engine make sure that it is only that string that is present in a row with no word before or after it

Comment: @jamesjelo4kul Thanks for replaying.
I didn't understand you so much. but never mine.
I found an answer but i must explain on something , look at this code:

`code`
SELECT ID, MyText
FROM TestTable
WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), MyText) = N'AnyText'
GO
`code`

i have to convert name var in my code to varchar ? why is that?

Answer (score 0):

**Like**

The LIKE operator is used to search for a specified pattern in a column.

**Where**

The WHERE clause is used to extract only those records that fulfill a specified criterion.

In your case the first query do not work is because no records match the criteria you are searching.